# Authorization token can not be forwarded into server side correctly

Tags: angular, header, authorization, token, httpclient

I implemented AuthTokenInterceptor as below. My problem is that the Authorization token can not be forwarded into server side correctly. I am sure that I can get authentication token by request.headers.get("Authorization") right before I pass the request into next.handler().

I found that the request had been sent twice, the first one had no Authorization header but the second one had the header.

I removed the retry from pipe, but there are still two requests sent to the server side.

There is a special case for my project. I used a third-party i18n tool and it requires old HttpModule from '@angular/http'. So I import both HttpModule and HttpClientModule.

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (this.authService.getAccessToken()) {
      request = this.addToken(request);
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse 
        && ( error.status === 401 || error.status == 403) ) {
        if ( error.status == 401 )
          return this.handle401Error(error, request, next);
        else
          return this.handle403Error(error, request, next);
      } else {
        return throwError(error);
      }
    }));
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
    const tokenName = this.authService.getAuthorizationTokenName();
    const tokenValue = this.authService.getAuthorizationTokenValue();

    // Clone the request and replace the original headers with
    // cloned headers, updated with the authorization.
    const authReq = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set(tokenName, tokenValue)
    });
    return authReq;
  }
```

Comment: Your first request is probably OPTIONS call which used when client address doesn't match API address, to check for CORS policies. This is something that is issued by the browser and has nothing to do with the Angular itself.

Comment: Yes, the first request is OPTIONS request. I have permitted OPTIONS request in the server side without authentication verification.

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor only receive one request but there are two requests sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason for the double requests. The first request is CORS option request. That's why it doesn't contain Authorization header.